# How to output Chinese word in batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I am using following code to out put Chinese word by batch file.

```
@echo off

echo  成功 
echo  失敗 
echo  開始
```

But it show garbled word.

```
 ??
 憭望?
 ??
```

How to output Chinese word in batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save batch file type to ANSI file extension:

1. Using windows text editor
2. choose "Save As..."
3. "encoding" choose "ANSI"
4. Press "save" button to .

execute the bat file and it will show correct word.

```
 成功
 失敗
 開始
```

Thanks for [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun) recommend:

More generally you need to use an editor that can save the batch file as UTF-8 without a BOM, such as notepad++. Then at the top run the command chcp.com 65001. The UTF-8 codepage (65001) is buggy in the console, so you should really only do this temporarily, i.e. first save the previous codepage and restore it after reading the strings into environment variables.

Comment: That's only if your ANSI and OEM codepages are the same, i.e. a DBCS codepage; the codepage supports Chinese characters -- e.g. codepage 936 or 950; and the current console font has glyphs for the given characters.

Comment: More generally you need to use an editor that can save the batch file as UTF-8 without a BOM, such as notepad++. Then at the top run the command `chcp.com 65001`. The UTF-8 codepage (65001) is buggy in the console, so you should really only do this temporarily, i.e. first save the previous codepage and restore it after reading the strings into environment variables.

Comment: Thanks for recommend :)

Answer (score 1):

If you redirect echo Chinese to file with `chcp 950` or `chcp 936`, then opening the file in notepad will display symbols.
Reading the file, however, will display Chinese in CMD if still in **same codepage**:
`type <outfile>`

Reading file in **different codepage** will yield a mix of other characters eg. if echo with `950` and read with `936`

Viewing file in notepad will display Chinese if echo in codepage 65001: 
`chcp 65001`

Codepages 936 & 950 will display symbols in notepad, but will still display Chinese in CMD (when file is viewed by `type` command). 
Codepage 65001 will display symbols in CMD but will display Chinese when output file is opened in Notepad.

eg.

```
echo off
chcp 936
echo 他的遺產無法估量，他是美國歷史最具影響力的告密者之一>test
type test
他的遺產無法估量，他是美國歷史最具影響力的告密者之一
chcp 950
Active code page: 950
type test
坻腔朡家楊嘛講ㄛ坻岆藝妢郔撿荌?薯腔豢躇氪眳珨
```

The above saves/writes Chinese characters to files via Win CMD, and does **not** rely on (without involving) Windows GUI/Notepad(++) to `File -> Save As` Unicode/UTF-8/BOMless

Tested in Win 10.